# Page redirected is causing a problem to select the correct active page

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm using Squarespace, set the page "danieconz.com/about" as my homepage and, as so, it gets redirected to "danielconz.com".

I've created links to pages at the footer and some CSS codes. My problem is that, when I'm at "danielconz.com" these links get all selected. However, only the "About" link should be selected.

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
    @media all and (max-width:750px) {
#footer h1 {
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 70px!important;
 }
#footer h1 .active-link {
  border-top: 2px solid #1a1611;
}
#footer h1 a:hover {
  border-top: 2px solid #1a1611;
}
}

@media all and (min-width:750px) {
#footer h1 a:hover {
  border-top: 2px solid #1a1611;
  padding: 0px !important;
}

#footer h1 .active-link  {
  border-top: 2px solid #1a1611;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
}
```

And follow a couple of images of the problem on desktop and mobile. Could anyone please help me with that? 
Thanks in advance.

[desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XA1f.jpg)
[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhuNv.jpg)

Comment: Can you share both pages html code too?

Comment: @FabioAssuncao I'm a layman and am not sure how I can do that... Here's the link of the page where the problem is happening: [link](https://www.danielconz.com/) Hope this helps...

Comment: Okay, I am gonna check and see if I figure out something.

Comment: I have updated the question. It's kind of a problem of recognizing the "About" home page as the active link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a javascript adding the link-active class to the links in your footer.

A quick thing you can do is change the function to this, please check it:

```
$(function() {
if(location.pathname.split("/")[1]==""){
    $('footer h1 a').removeClass('active-link');
    $('footer h1 a[href^="/about"]').addClass('active-link');
}else{
    $('footer h1 a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active-link');
}
$('body').addClass('enter');//This part is the same
});
```

Comment: I am glad to hear it! And checking your site it looks like you are in Sao Paulo, I am from there!

Comment: Que massa! Tá morando no Japão?